# Python Kivy unable to click on text input (can't click into TextInput) inside an ActionBar dropdown menu on windows

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I setup a simple menu with a series of buttons and a drop down (overflow) using an ActionBar. The name of the drop down section in the menu is "Settings". When I click on "Settings" a drop down appears showing the three TextInput widgets that it holds.

When I try to click on (or into) any of the TextInputs the drop down closes. To make matters worse this problem only occurs on Windows operating systems it works fine on linux.

**Can anyone explain why I'm unable to click on (or into) the TextInputs?**

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionItem

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class ActionInput(TextInput, ActionItem):
    pass


class mScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
mScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
<MainScreen>:  
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Menu'
                with_previous: False
           ActionOverflow:
           ActionButton:
               id: b_1
               text: 'b_1'
               on_release: 
           ActionButton:
               id: b_2
               text: 'b_2'
               on_release:
           ActionButton:
               id: b_3
               text: 'b_3'
               on_release:
           ActionButton:
               id: b_4
               text: 'b_4'
               on_release:
           ActionButton:
               id: b_5
               text: 'b_5'
           ActionButton:
               id: b_6
               text: 'b_6'
               on_release:
           ActionGroup:
               text: 'Settings'
               mode: 'spinner'
               ActionInput:
                    id: t_input_1
                    hint_text: "Can't click"
                    multiline: False
                    on_text_validate: 
               ActionInput:
                   id: t_input_2
                   hint_text: "can't click"
                   multiline: False
                   on_text_validate:
               ActionInput:
                   id: t_input_3
                   hint_text: "Can't click"
                   multiline: False
                   on_text_validate:
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Example App'
        return root_widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: The behavior you describe for Windows happens under Ubuntu for me.

Comment: Strange, this has been tested on multiple releases of Ubuntu, Kubuntu, and Arch and has worked fine for me on all of them. Is this happening for you on windows systems as well, or does it work on windows for you?

Comment: I get identical behavior under Windows 10 and Ubuntu. When I click on `Settings`, I get the dropdown of TextInput items. When I click on any of the three TextInput items, the dropdown closes. I am running Python v3.6.1 and Kivy v1.10.0. on both. I did have to edit some indentation in your `kv` string to get it to run, but I don't think that should be an issue.

Comment: My apologies. I reformatted when I pasted it here; For reference I’m using python 3.6.4 on both windows 10 and all my Linux installs. I’m also using kivy 1.10 on Windows 10 and 1.9 on my Linux OS. After downgrading on windows the issue is still present. I searched on GitHub for similar issues and after searching for a while saw that there are similar issues with the action bar on windows 10. I did open a bug report as well and I’m hoping to get a response. When I do I’ll update this.